# How can I filter differences of datasets in a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am relativly new to SQL and I have a short question. I already searched for similar questions in stackOverflow but I couldn't find anything.I have created some Views. These Views change from one Version to antother. To make migration easier for the customer, I want to filter differences in data_types of columns between two versions. Currently I'm working PostgreSQL Version 11.16

I have table that looks like this:

| versionsnummer | install_timestamp | column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 2023-06-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_01 | integer |
| D1 | 2023-06-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_04 | character varying |
| D2 | 2023-07-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_01 | integer |
| D2 | 2023-07-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_04 | integer |

Now I want to find all rows where the value of the column data_type has changed between two versions.
So I'm expecting the following result:

| versionsnummer | install_timestamp | column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 2023-06-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_04 | character varying |
| D2 | 2023-06-02 06:42:14.531588 | t0801_04 | integer |

What I've tried is this:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (column_name, data_type) column_name, data_type FROM mytable WHERE versionsnummer = 'D1' OR versionsnummer = 'D2';`

Unfortunately I didn't get the expectes Result with this query. Could you please tell me waht i'm doing wrong here?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this via "SELF JOIN". Join the tables with itself on "column_name" column.

Here is the code:

```
SELCT t1.versionsnummer, t1.install_timestamp, t1.column_name, t1.data_type
FROM [your_table_name] t1
JOIN [your_table_name] t2 ON t1.column_name = t2.column_name
WHERE t1.data_type <> t2.data_type;
```

Example: If you select all columns from the table, you will get:

| versionsnummer | install_timestamp | column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 2023-06-02 06:42:14.531 | t0801_04 | character_varing |
| D2 | 2023-07-02 06:42:14.531 | t0801_04 | integer |

Tested [here](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html):
[image]

*Don't forget to change table name in this query!

Comment: I don't think this has the desired result when there are three versions with different datatypes per column